# Text Gradient whith sIFR 3

Tags: javascript, text, fonts, sifr, gradient

I want to use sIFR 3 to add a simple linear gradient filter to a text, I can't find this in the ducumentation hope you guys can give me some help.

I found an article that show's how to do this but requiers the modification of the flash file and that's not what I want to do.

I looked in the sIFR documentaion and I didn't found a Gradient filter, I hope this effect can be made simple using the sIFR filters.

Thank's

Answer (score 0):

sIFR 3 supports the text filters, see http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/Filters.

Comment: I know, but I cant find a filter that makes a gradient.

Comment: I wouldn't know either, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The two gradients that this supports seem to be "Gradient Bevel Filter" and "Gradient Glow Filter". I could be wrong, but based on some Web searches, these do not seem to support linear gradients. Rather, they seem to support gradients on the borders of the text.

Would be nice if there was a way to do linear gradients as there appears to be with Cufon:
  http://cufon.shoqolate.com/examples/gradient.html

If you do have that article describing modification of the Flash file, to achieve it in sIFR, could you post it here?